# How do I list the honorary titles that I've granted?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I am playing as a count and granted honorary titles to a few persons early on in the game.  Now I want to grant a title to a new vassal, but I suspect I have run out of titles to grant (the button is gray and says "We have no honorary titles to grant to...").

Is there any convenient way to list granted honorary titles?  Or do I have to manually browse through my court and vassals?

I am playing the vanilla version of the game, no DLCs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature to list honorary titles has now been implemented. To list the titles, go to your *Council* and click *Minor Titles*:

[image: Minor Titles]

---

### Previous answer which applies to older versions of the game

After playing the game for a few months, and also downloaded most of the DLCs, I think I now can answer my own question.

**No, it is not possible to list the honorary titles that have been granted.**

The reason I asked this from the beginning is because I want to keep my vassals happy to maximise income and armies.

What I tend to do is browse through my vassals every now and then and:

- If they just slightly dislike me, grant an honorary title if available.
- If the person hates me, I tend to plot to kill him/her.
- Perform other actions to increase the relationship (sending gifts, granting titles, etc)